# Sending email using C# often ends up in spam folder

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, spam, mailkit

I am sending email from my outlook email using **MailKit** package of C#.
However, for same email body and subject when I send it using Outlook app, it ends up in recipient inbox. But when I send it using my program it ends up in spam folder. Here is my code sample:

```
    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sender Name", "sender@example.com"));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", "recipient@example.com"));
    message.Subject = "Test Email";
    message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
    {
        Text = "This is a test email sent using MailKit."
    };

    message.Headers.Add("X-Priority", "2");
    message.Headers.Add("X-MSMail-Priority", "Normal");

    // create the SMTP client
    using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
    {
        // connect to the SMTP server
        client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 587, false);

        // authenticate with the SMTP server
        client.Authenticate("sender@example.com", "password");

        // send the message
        client.Send(message);

        // disconnect from the SMTP server
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
```

**I am not sure why it is behaving different when I send mail using this code . Help me how can I improve the code to not ending up in spam or let me know if there any other solution.**

Comment: Are you sending spam? If so, then it's been classified correctly. If not, then show  an example of what you're sending.

Comment: Sometimes frecuency of the sendings or the content of it could be flagged as spam. And it is the destination server the one that decides if it is classified as spam or not. You may consider checking those two factors (and so far you question lacks information about them).

Comment: @user09938 The content is not spammy. Because when I send same email using app that does not end up in spam folder rather it is going into inbox. Why is that for same text?

Comment: Does your email server properly use DMARC, SPF, DKIM? Check some of the tools at https://mxtoolbox.com/dmarc/dmarc-email-tools?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI9O_ur5Cd_QIV2ObjBx2AqQzGEAAYBCAAEgJUiPD_BwE

Also, you mentioned using mailkit. It has great support for OAuth which makes it easy to push a lot of these problems onto gmail.

Comment: @clamchoda They should. Because I am using an outlook email.

Comment: @RobinKhan are you using a real account in the `message.From` or does it differ from what's used in `client.Authenticate`? You can spoof any name in the `message.From` account but if it doesn't match the authentication of a real account it will surely be flagged as spam.

Comment: I assume the app you mentioned doesn't use SMTP but something else. If you have the mails in the target mailbox then check/compare the headers there how they differ. For example most systems will mark mails considered spam with a telling header field.